# Joint pdf of Poisson processes

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

I recently stumbled upon this question:

Let T1 and T2 be the times for the first and second jump of a Poisson process
with rate λ > 0. Find the joint probability density function of T1 and T2

After formulating that:

$ P(T_1 <= s, T_2 <= t) = P(X(s)>=1, X(t)>=2) =  ... = (1-P(X(s) =0)) * (1 - P(X(t-s) = 0) = 1 - e^{- \lambda s }- e^{- \lambda (t-s) } + e^{- \lambda t }$

and then taking the derivative with respect to t and s to get the joint pdf I end up with

$ f(s,t) = \lambda^2 e^{-\lambda (t-s) }$

however the correct answer should be apparently be $ f(s,t) = \lambda^2 e^{-\lambda t }$

does anyone know where I do my mistake?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed cases where $X(s) \ge 2$ while $X(t-s) = 0$.

\begin{align}
P(T_1 \le s, T_2 \le t)
&= P(X(s) \ge 1, X(t) \ge 2)
\\
&= P(X(s) = 1, X(t-s) \ge 1) + P(X(s) \ge 2)
\\
&= P(X(s) = 1) P(X(t-s) \ge 1) + P(X(s) \ge 2)
\\
&= \lambda s e^{-\lambda s} (1 - e^{-\lambda(t-s)}) + (1 - e^{-\lambda s} - \lambda s e^{-\lambda s})
\\
&= -\lambda s e^{-\lambda t} + 1 - e^{-\lambda s}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't really get this though... why does the split require X(s) = 1 and and additional term of P(X(s)>=2)? 

Do you know what this "rule" is called or where I could understand this better perhaps

Comment: @Stats Just careful casework on how many jumps in the intervals $[0, s]$ and $[s, t]$ would lead to the event $\{X(s) \ge 1, X(t) \ge 2\}$. Your calculation missed some cases, as I mentioned at the beginning of my answer.

Comment: okay, think I kinda get it, but what I don't understand is why the second term P(X(s) >=2) does not include P(X(s) >=2, X(t-s) =0) ? shouldnt that also be a part of that term?

Comment: If $X(s) \ge 2$, then $X(t-s)$ can be anything. You had already counted the cases $X(t-s) \ge 1$ in your solution thouogh.